# Extract from 2nd column based on string content in 1st column

Tags: r

Please help, I need to extract all entries from column B 
which appear against those in Column A from a data frame

I need to search Column A based on string which has GK104
That is, if column A has `GK104` in its enries, it will fetch corresponding entry from column B

```
A                    B
DT-GK104-BIN1-E-A1  8000_AMKR
DT-GK104-BIN2-E-A2  8000_ASET
DT-GK104-BIN3-E-A1  8000_CPAC
DT-GK104-BIN4-E-ZK  8000_PWOO
DT-GK104-BIN5-E-ZK  8000_SPIL
```

Comment: `grep("GK104",df$A)` will give a vector of the row numbers in which column A contains `GK104`.  You can then use this to reference column B.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. To continue Andrew Gustar's comment, you just need to use `grepl`:

```
df <- 
"A                    B
DT-GK104-BIN1-E-A1  8000_AMKR
DT-GK104-BIN2-E-A2  8000_ASET
DT-GK104-BIN3-E-A1  8000_CPAC
DT-GK104-BIN4-E-ZK  8000_PWOO
DT-GK104-BIN5-E-ZK  8000_SPIL"

df <- read.table(text=df, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Save a value which you want to match
value <- "A1"

# You can get a filtered dataframe
df[grepl(value, df$A),]
                   A         B
1 DT-GK104-BIN1-E-A1 8000_AMKR
3 DT-GK104-BIN3-E-A1 8000_CPAC

# Or you can just get a character vector of matched values in the second column 
df$B[grepl(value, df$A)]
[1] "8000_AMKR" "8000_CPAC"
```